# Change icon in tab bar using Framework 7 in intel xdk

Tags: tabbar, intel-xdk, html-framework-7

I am using tabbar in intel xdk using Framework 7. It only supports [few icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McUM7.jpg) and I need to use custom icons or the native icons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) or just remove `<i>` tag and add image from your assets.

```
<div class="left">
    <a href="#" class="link"><img src="..."></a>
</div>
```