# How to add more tab bar icon in intel xdk

Tags: icons, tabbar, intel-xdk

I want to know how to add more tab bar icon in intel xdk instead of using their provided icon which is limited to 17 icon only. I'm searching for the solution and i found one but cannot be used. This one [Change icon in tab bar using Framework 7 in intel xdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349476/change-icon-in-tab-bar-using-framework-7-in-intel-xdk). I try the custom url method but the image not in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Framework 7, you can easily add more icons and call them as if they where default icons.

CSS:

```
i.icon.your-icon-name {
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    background-image: url(url/to/image);
}
```

HTML (example):

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="#" class="link icon-only">
                <i class="icon your-icon-name"></i>
            </a><
        /div>
        <div class="center">Navbar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```